# How to download file from byte base64 in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, base64, byte

I have string of byte base64

```
let string = 'UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBi7...'
```

How should I do, if I want download the file from the byte base64 in vue js

Thanks, any solution is so help me :')

Answer (score 2):

i found this nice library https://github.com/rndme/download

you just import this in you library and then

```
download("data:image/gif;base64,R0ln5+......n4/+oMSAAOw==", "dlDUrlBin.gif", "image/gif");
```

let me know if is useful

Comment: if I want a csv file format. is it true if like this > data:application/csv ?

Comment: idk, maybe text/csv;charset=utf-8;